# Making a gift finder using attributes

Tags: magento-1.8, layered-navigation, filter, filterable-attributes

I'm working on a really simple gift finder at the moment. So far I only have a gift finder category that is  filtering products by price range, but i would like to add some more choices as well - age, gender and maybe occasion seems fitting for a start.

I suppose the best way to do this would be to add the choices as attributes to the products, and use an extension that adds the possibility of choosing multiple filters at the same time.

However, this gives me 2 problems. The attributes are totally irrelevant for all other categories. Can I make them used only for this gift finder category?

Also - i need to add attributes to some 2000 products. Is there any way i can select multiple products and give them all the same attribute?

If theres a better solution to this, please let me know.

Comment: You can use attribute sets for having attributes only to that category,  also mass update of attributes is too a default feature from admin product grid. Take a look at the documentation for details of both.

Comment: Thanks! Ill be sure to read up on that. I just supposed that if the products were in other categories as well, they would also list the attributes there :-)

Comment: And that's why Magento is "Magento" !